# Why SQL INSERT INTO SELECT statement duplicates the rows?

Tags: c#, sql-server

I am using C# windows application and I created this stored procedures to save old result and new result but the procedure duplicates each row 2 times save one row for old result and one row for new result , I need to insert only one row for each result which is the old result only

this is the stored procedure code :

```
CREATE proc [dbo].[UPDATED_RESULTS]
@ORDER_ID int,
@TESTID int,
@APPROVED_BY varchar(50),
@APPROVED_DATE datetime, 
@RESULT_NUMBER varchar(50),
@MACHINE_ID int,
@patient_no int,
@custid int,
@CORRECTED_BY varchar(50),
@CORRECTED_DATE datetime,
@messageid int
AS
INSERT INTO [dbo].[LAB_RESULTS_UPDATED]
           ([ORDER_ID]
           ,[TESTID]
           ,[APPROVED_BY]
           ,[APPROVED_DATE]
           ,[RESULT_NUMBER]
           ,[machine_id]
           ,[patient_no]
           ,[custid]
           ,[CORRECTED_BY]
           ,[CORRECTED_DATE]
           ,[messageid])
     SELECT DISTINCT ORDER_ID,TESTID ,APPROVED_BY ,APPROVED_DATE ,RESULT_NUMBER ,MACHINE_ID ,patient_no,custid,@CORRECTED_BY,@CORRECTED_DATE,@messageid
     FROM LAB_RESULTS 
     WHERE ORDER_ID = @ORDER_ID 
     AND RESULT_NUMBER IS NOT NULL 
     AND RESULT_NUMBER != '' 
     EXCEPT SELECT [ORDER_ID],[TESTID],[APPROVED_BY],[APPROVED_DATE],[RESULT_NUMBER],[machine_id],[patient_no],[custid],[CORRECTED_BY]
           ,[CORRECTED_DATE]
           ,[messageid]
     FROM LAB_RESULTS_UPDATED
```

and this is the class code in C# application when click save button:

```
for (int i = 0; i < dgvResult.Rows.Count; i++)
{
    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(dgvResult.Rows[i].Cells[3].Value.ToString()))
    {
        result.UPDATED_RESULTS(
            Convert.ToInt32(txtOrder.Text),
            Convert.ToInt32(dgvResult.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value),
            txtApprovedby.Text,
            DateTime.Parse(dateTimeApprove.Value.ToString()),
            dgvResult.Rows[i].Cells[3].Value.ToString(),
            Convert.ToInt32(dgvResult.Rows[i].Cells[4].Value.ToString()),
            Convert.ToInt32(txtMRN.Text),
            Convert.ToInt32(textCustId.Text),
            txtApprovedby.Text,
            DateTime.Parse(dateTimeApprove.Value.ToString()),1);
        result.APPROVE_ALLLAB_RESULTS_NEW(
            Convert.ToInt32(txtOrder.Text),
            txtApprovedby.Text,
            DateTime.Parse(dateTimeApprove.Value.ToString()),
            Convert.ToInt32(dgvResult.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value),
            dgvResult.Rows[i].Cells[3].Value.ToString(),
            "No Report",
            Convert.ToInt32(dgvResult.Rows[i].Cells[4].Value.ToString()),
            Convert.ToInt32(txtMRN.Text),
            Convert.ToInt32(textCustId.Text),
            Convert.ToInt32(txtUpdateCount),
            txtExamUser.Text,
            DateTime.Parse(DateTimeExamined.Value.ToString()),6);
    }
}
```

How to update the stored procedure to save only one row the old result ?

Comment: SUGGESTION:  Try getting the SQL to work in SSMS / TSQL first (as pure SQL), THEN try to get it working in the C# application program, please.

Comment: Perhaps use `NOT EXISTS` instead of `EXCEPT` then you can choose exactly which columns to check for

Comment: @JosephDoggie I tried it in SQL without the EXCEPT part its not duplicates the rows but when I used it in application its duplicates each row depends on the rows numbers in DATAGRID for example if 5 rows then each result duplicated 5 times then I searched and found this EXCEPT solution but save old and new result and I will try NOT EXIST

Comment: are you running the proc twice?  the call is in a loop `for (int i = 0; i < dgvResult.Rows.Count; i++)`

Comment: @Hogan No I loop the procedure for each row in DATAGRID view and its save old result then SELECT the new result from the table LAB_RESULTS and insert it again into LAB_RESULTS_UPDATED

Comment: @Charlieface how to use NOT EXISTS instead of EXCEPT ?

Comment: It's possible that they are not actually duplicates, but only appear to be.  For instance, leading/trailing spaces in one of your varchar, or an unprintable character, or an unprinted microsecond difference in a datetime column, etc.  You can throw a Key on the columns to check for this.  If the Key doesn't object, then they're not true duplicates.

Comment: is order id unique?  or maybe the combination of order id and test id

Comment: @Hogan one order_id can include multiple tests (test id) yes ORDER_ID unique

Comment: if there can be multiple than it is not unique.   can there be more than one of a given combination of test_id and order_id?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe this is what you want:

```
INSERT INTO [dbo].[LAB_RESULTS_UPDATED]
           ([ORDER_ID]
           ,[TESTID]
           ,[APPROVED_BY]
           ,[APPROVED_DATE]
           ,[RESULT_NUMBER]
           ,[machine_id]
           ,[patient_no]
           ,[custid]
           ,[CORRECTED_BY]
           ,[CORRECTED_DATE]
           ,[messageid])
     SELECT DISTINCT ORDER_ID,TESTID ,APPROVED_BY ,APPROVED_DATE ,RESULT_NUMBER ,MACHINE_ID ,patient_no,custid,@CORRECTED_BY,@CORRECTED_DATE,@messageid
     FROM LAB_RESULTS 
     LEFT JOIN (SELECT [ORDER_ID],[TESTID] FROM LAB_RESULTS_UPDATED) EX 
       ON LAB_RESULTS.ORDER_ID = EX.ORDER_ID AND LAB_RESULTS.TESTID = EX.TESTID
     WHERE ORDER_ID = @ORDER_ID 
     AND RESULT_NUMBER IS NOT NULL 
     AND RESULT_NUMBER != '' 
     AND EX.ORDER_ID IS NULL
```

Here I am doing a left join and only using items that are null -- this is the same as a "NOT EXISTS" but it allows you to join on two fields

NOTE: This assumes that there is only ever one of any combination of order_id and testid (which would be a standard relational design)

Comment: thank you so much I will try the solution :)

Answer (score 0):

NOT EXIST solved the duplicates , I added this line in where statement :

```
AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT TESTID FROM [LAB_RESULTS_UPDATED] WHERE ORDER_ID = @ORDER_ID)
```

and select distinct TESTID first instead of ORDER_ID
and removed EXCEPT SELECT

this is the complete stored procedure :

```
ALTER proc [dbo].[UPDATED_RESULTS]
@ORDER_ID int,
@TESTID int,
@APPROVED_BY varchar(50),
@APPROVED_DATE datetime, 
@RESULT_NUMBER varchar(50),
@MACHINE_ID int,
@patient_no int,
@custid int,
@CORRECTED_BY varchar(50),
@CORRECTED_DATE datetime,
@messageid int
AS
INSERT INTO [dbo].[LAB_RESULTS_UPDATED]
           ([TESTID]
           ,[ORDER_ID]
           ,[APPROVED_BY]
           ,[APPROVED_DATE]
           ,[RESULT_NUMBER]
           ,[machine_id]
           ,[patient_no]
           ,[custid]
           ,[CORRECTED_BY]
           ,[CORRECTED_DATE]
           ,[messageid])
     SELECT DISTINCT TESTID , ORDER_ID ,APPROVED_BY ,APPROVED_DATE ,RESULT_NUMBER ,MACHINE_ID ,patient_no,custid,@CORRECTED_BY,@CORRECTED_DATE,@messageid
     FROM LAB_RESULTS 
     WHERE ORDER_ID = @ORDER_ID 
     AND RESULT_NUMBER IS NOT NULL 
     AND RESULT_NUMBER != '' 
     AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT TESTID FROM [LAB_RESULTS_UPDATED] WHERE ORDER_ID = @ORDER_ID)
```

Comment: Just to point out -- this will not insert the record if there is ANY record with a TESTID for a given  ORDER_ID.  So if there can be more than one test per order this will stop them from being saved which is unexpected.